# Error "Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE) in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I tried to run an nginx server on my Mac with:

```
docker container run --publish 80:80 nginx
```

It is returning this error.

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint hungry_shtern (88e68bd0a448ebe25a62c1c897d38a58e7cc581736ea55a0b764197d0416fce6): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).

How to fix this?

Comment: Port is already in use by another process. Probably another instance if the same Nginx image. Stop all containers first.

Comment: @Timir there is no running container, whenever i try to use another port, my terminal hangs

Comment: EADDRINUSE means `localhost:80` is occupied. So it isn't another container. Do you know how to use `netstat`? Good time to learn.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers pointed, that port is already in use by some other service.

This service is the default apache installed on mac.

To confirm, try:

```
sudo lsof -i:80
```

And if you see the command `httpd` appearing there, the apache server is running, and using port 80.

You could also just try to access http://localhost:80 on your browser. If the apache server is running, you'll see something like "It works!".

To disable this service:

```
sudo apachectl -k stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

After the first command you will be able to bind that port with docker. After the second, you'll disable `apachectl` on startup.

Comment: I get AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message when running first cmd

Comment: also got: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service when running second cmd

Answer (score 0):

Maybe port 80 is in use by another process, you need to kill that process or change bind port of docker container:

```
docker container run --publish 8080:80 nginx
```